# Are there any good node js file servers?

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a versatile, feature rich node js file server?

Does such a thing exist? Preferably, thumbnail support, download files (potentially multiple files) etc.

Would be great to hear back!

Comment: I was googling around a little while ago for something very similar to this. Let me know if you find anything.

Comment: Check out Cachemere://github.com/topcloud/cachemere

Answer (score 1):

Check out blueimp's file upload plugin at https://npmjs.org/package/blueimp-file-upload-jquery-ui

If you're just looking for a static file server without a dependency on jQuery, check out https://github.com/alejandro/Houston

Hope this helps.